# In this code, why is get executing before post and why do i have to select 2 values in the dropdown before it is stored in the variable?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have two errors with the code, the app.get is executed before app.post and i have to select 2 different values in the dropdown before the value is stored in the variable

> **nodejs**: getBrandandManufacturer1 returns the details from medicine database where the brandname matches and stores in an array.
> getBrandandManufacturer sends the array to the front end

```
    var testvar=[];
    let getBrandandManufacturersql1 = `SELECT * FROM medicinedatabase where Brandname=? `;
    app.post("/getBrandandManufacturer1", (req, res) => {
        var jtBrandname = req.body.Brandname;
        db.query(getBrandandManufacturersql1,[jtBrandname],(err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                testvar.push(result)
                //res.send(result)
                console.log("getBrandandManufacturersql",testvar)
            }
    
        });
    });
    
    app.get("/getBrandandManufacturer", (req, res) => {
                res.send(testvar)
                console.log("getBrandandManufacturersql2",testvar)
             
      
    });
```

> **reactjs**: When a value is select the query is executed in the onchange

```
    const [Brandname, setBrandname] = useState();
    const [Manufacturer, setManufacturer] = useState();
    const [brandnamemedicineList, setbrandnamemedicineList] = useState([])
    const [manufacmedicineList, setmanufacmedicineList] = useState([])
    <div className="addMed">
                <div className ="inputcss">
    
                    <select className="inputfield" name="Brand Name" onChange={(event) => {
                        setBrandname(event.target.value);;
                        console.log("brandname",Brandname)
                        Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/getBrandandManufacturer1', {
                            Brandname: Brandname,
                        }).then(() => {
                          console.log("Success!");
                        });
                        Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/getBrandandManufacturer').then((response) => {
                            setmanufacmedicineList(response.data);
                             console.log("Update",response)
                   });
                    }}>
                        {brandnamemedicineList.map((e, key) => {
                            return <option  value={e.Brandname}>{e.Brandname}</option>;
                        })}
                    </select>
    
                    <select  className="inputfield" name="Manufacturer" onChange={(event) => {setManufacturer(event.target.value);}}>
                        {manufacmedicineList.map((e, key) => {
                            return <option  value={e.Manufacturer}>{e.Manufacturer}</option>;
                        })}
                    </select>
```

Comment: What makes you think the `app.get` is executed before the `app.post`? The code looks to be synchronous and Javascript doesn't skip around within a function when it's executing. The `app.post` is executed and then immediately after the `app.get` is executed. Seems you are asking about a couple (possibly unrelated) issues. Can you narrow the scope of your question to a single specific issue, include details about what the errors are?

Comment: You need to call Axios.get after you get response from Axios.post. In your code you are calling them simultaneously. Try this `Axios.post(...).then(() => { Axios.get(...).then(...); });`

Comment: @Molda It worked thanks!!